# Conditional merging of Pandas DataFrames in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames that currently looks like this:

```
raw_data = {'SeriesDate':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15','2017-03-16','2017-03-17']}
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['SeriesDate'])
df1['SeriesDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SeriesDate'])
print df1

 SeriesDate
0 2017-03-10
1 2017-03-13
2 2017-03-14
3 2017-03-15
4 2017-03-16
5 2017-03-17

raw_data2 = {'SeriesDate':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15','2017-03-16'],'NewSeriesDate':['2017-03-11','2017-03-12','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-14']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data2,columns=['SeriesDate','NewSeriesDate'])
df2['SeriesDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SeriesDate'])
print df2

SeriesDate NewSeriesDate
0 2017-03-10    2017-03-11
1 2017-03-13    2017-03-12
2 2017-03-14    2017-03-13
3 2017-03-15    2017-03-14
4 2017-03-16    2017-03-14
```

1) I would like to join the dataframes in such a manner that for all 'SeriesDate' in df1 before 15th March, the 'NewSeriesDate' values should be taken from df2.

2) For any 'SeriesDate' in df1 after 15th March or for any 'SeriesDate' that are not in df2, the 'NewSeriesDate' should be calculated as follows:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
df1['NewSeriesDate'] = df1[''SeriesDate'] - BDay(1)
```

As an example, my final DataFrame in this scenario would look like this:

```
raw_data3 = {'SeriesDate':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15','2017-03-16','2017-03-17'],'NewSeriesDate':['2017-03-11','2017-03-12','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15','2017-03-16']}
finaldf = pd.DataFrame(raw_data3,columns=['SeriesDate','NewSeriesDate'])
finaldf['SeriesDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SeriesDate'])
print finaldf

 SeriesDate NewSeriesDate
0 2017-03-10    2017-03-11
1 2017-03-13    2017-03-12
2 2017-03-14    2017-03-13
3 2017-03-15    2017-03-14
4 2017-03-16    2017-03-15
5 2017-03-17    2017-03-16
```

I am new to Pandas so not sure how to apply conditional merge, can anyone provide some insight please?

Comment: Can you post what your desired output looks like? It's a little hard to follow with just the narrative.

Comment: Thanks - just posted the output

Comment: Couple other notes: no need to import pandas twice, and I would recommend naming your dataframes with df1, df2, or something similar. Your dataframe named "series" is confusing since pandas also has series types that are often within dataframes. It will help others answer this question.

Comment: Thanks have fixed this

Comment: Did the solution work for you? If so, please accept the answer, of not, let us know what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  It could probably be a little cleaner, but does the trick.  You didn't specify what happens if the date is exactly March 15th, so I made an assumption.  I may have switched out some header names, but you get the idea:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'SeriesDate':pd.to_datetime(['3/10/17','3/13/17','3/14/17','3/15/17','3/16/17','3/17/17']),
    })

df1['NewSeries'] = np.nan

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'SeriesDate':pd.to_datetime(['3/10/17','3/13/17','3/14/17','3/15/17','3/16/17']),
    'NewSeries':pd.to_datetime(['3/11/17','3/12/17','3/13/17','3/14/17','3/14/17'])
    })

d = pd.to_datetime('3/15/17')

df1.loc[df1['SeriesDate'] <= d]  = df1.loc[df1['SeriesDate'] <= d].set_index('SeriesDate') \
    .combine_first(df2.loc[df2['SeriesDate'] <= d].set_index('SeriesDate')).reset_index()

df1.loc[df1['SeriesDate'] > d, 'NewSeries'] = df1['SeriesDate'] - BDay(1)
```